# SignalR client doesn't work inside AngularJs controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, signalr, signalr.client

I've created Angular application based on routes.
Without using the routes, the Signalr works fine, but when I work with routes, the Signalr works just in one way - from client side to server.

```
<html ng-app="SignalR">
<head>
//Scripts
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#/Today">Today</a>
<a href="#/History">History</a>

<div ng-view>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var hubConnetion = undefined;
    hubConnetion = $.connection.hubs;
    $.connection.hub.start();


    var SignalRControllers = angular.module('SignalRControllers', []);

    var SignalRApp = angular.module('SignalR', ['ngRoute', 'SignalRControllers']);


    SignalRApp.config(['$routeProvider',
      function ($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider.
            when('/Today', {
                templateUrl: '@Url.Action("Today","Home")'
            }).
            when('/History', {
                templateUrl: '@Url.Action("History", "Home")'
            })
      }]);

</script>
<script src="~/AngularJs/TodayController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*TodayController.js*

```
SignalRControllers.controller('TodayController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {

      $scope.sendTask = function () {
          hubConnetion.server.sendTask($("#taskName").val());//works
      }

      $scope.Task = "task1";
      hubConnetion.client.getTask= function (Task) {//never invoked
          $scope.Task = Task;
      }
  }]);
```

*Today.html*

```
<div ng-controller="TodayController">

    <div>{{Task}}</div>


    <input id="taskName" type="text" />
    <div ng-click="sendTask()">SendTask</div>

</div>
```

*Hubs.cs*

```
public class Hubs: Hub
{
   public void SendTask(string Name)
   {
      Clients.All.GetTask(Name);
   }
}
```

I'm not sure, but I think that because the *hubConnetion* variable is wrapped inside the controller, signlarR couldn't find it.
Is there any angular magic that can solve this ?

Comment: Pls add all code in Today.html, not just controller..

Comment: There is no more code, that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also fairly new to SignalR (and first time user of Angular) so I'v recreated (and simplified) the project in ASP.NET MVC 4 (SignalR 2.2) to nail the problem . And I think there is more then one...

1) SignalR is using JQuery. In jQuery  (and almost any other JS framework) its relly better to execute your code after 'document ready' event. So I wrapped SignalR setup in jQuery document ready handler (see code below).
Additionally I removed `hubConnetion` global variable because global variables are bad + after wrapping in jQuery document ready handler, variable is local to that handler and not accessible in controller code anyway...

2) **Main problem IMHO is this** (part of [SignalR client API](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#establishconnection)):

> Normally you register event handlers before calling the start method
>   to establish the connection. If you want to register some event
>   handlers after establishing the connection, you can do that, but you
>   must register at least one of your event handler(s) before calling the
>   start method. One reason for this is that there can be many Hubs in an
>   application, but you wouldn't want to trigger the OnConnected event on
>   every Hub if you are only going to use to one of them. When the
>   connection is established, the presence of a client method on a Hub's
>   proxy is what tells SignalR to trigger the OnConnected event. **If you
>   don't register any event handlers before calling the start method, you
>   will be able to invoke methods on the Hub, but the Hub's OnConnected
>   method won't be called and no client methods will be invoked from the
>   server**.

Your event handler is setup in controller factory method which is called much later then connection `start()` method.
Try to add *temporary* handler before calling `start()` like this:

`$.connection.tasklistHub.client.getTask = function () { };`

3) To be sure the problem is in SignalR and not Angular, i'v turned on both server and client side [tracing](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing). After all the changes above, event from server was successfully received on client:

`SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'getTask' on hub 'TasklistHub'`

But Angular failed to update div with data received. Solution is to use `$rootScope.$apply` function mentioned in [this article about using SignalR and Angular together](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.cz/2013/05/HookingUpAspNetSignalRWithAngularJS.html). Now everything works as expected. See full code below.

Sidenote: I understand this is just sample code. In any real world project I would consider wrapping SignalR hubs on client in some kind of service like in article mentioned above or using [this library](https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub) (looks very elegant)

I also take back my previous answer regarding the client side handler name as according to the same document, client side method name matching is case-insensitive...

*Index.cshtml*

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="SignalR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>SignalR & AngularJS</title>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $.connection.hub.logging = true;

                // temporary handler to force SignalR to subscribe to server events
                $.connection.tasklistHub.client.getTask = function () { };

                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    $('#connectionStatus').text('Connected');
                    console.log('Now connected, connection ID =' + $.connection.hub.id);
                });
            });

            var SignalRControllers = angular.module('SignalRControllers', []);
            var SignalRApp = angular.module('SignalR', ['SignalRControllers']);
        </script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/app/TodayController.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="body">
        <div ng-view>
            <div ng-controller="TodayController">

                <div id="connectionStatus"></div>

                <div>{{Task}}</div>

                <input id="taskName" type="text"/>
                <input type="button" name="Send Task" value="Send Task" data-ng-click="sendTask()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*TodayController.js*

```
SignalRControllers.controller('TodayController', [
        '$scope', '$http', '$rootScope',
        function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
            $scope.sendTask = function() {
                $.connection.tasklistHub.server.sendTask($("#taskName").val());
            };
            $scope.Task = "Empty";

            $.connection.tasklistHub.client.getTask = function (task) {
                console.log(task);
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.Task = task;
                });             
            };
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: What is the error message. Is there any ? Open Firebug or Chrome developer tools window and take a look at console messages. Try to add this `$.connection.hub.logging = true;
   $.connection.hub.error(function (error) {
    console.error('SignalR error: ' + error);
   });` before `$.connection.hub.start();`

Comment: I added your code, but there is no error message, also if I start debugging, when I invoke SendTask on click, it goes inside that hub function right like is expected, but after  `Clients.All.GetTask(Name);` nothing happens, `hubConnetion.client.getTask= function (Task) ` is never invoked

Comment: And the response from server is delivered to the browser ? (see Network tab in browser dev tools)

Comment: There is no response, but after that I took `hubConnetion.client.getTask= function (Task) ` ouside of the controller, and it works, but still there was no response from the server, only post methods like this `send?transport....`

Comment: Well it has probably something to do with how\when Angular runs yours controller constructor function. Im not expert on Angular so i cant help you. I would suggest to take a look at some tutorials on how to use SignalR with Angular (like this [one](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.cz/2013/09/ABetterWayOfUsingAspNetSignalRWithAngularJs.html)) or [this project](https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78881/discussion-between-tota-and-michal-levy).

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution is perfect and for those that face this problem even after your lecture, there is a simple solution to get response from server to client in every part of app:

```
    angular.module('groupApp').run(function ($rootScope, chat) {
        $rootScope.messages = [];
        chat.client.newMessage = function onNewMessage(message) {
           $rootScope.messages.push({ message: message });
           $rootScope.$apply();
    };
});
```

And in your view u are able to use 'messages' array everywhere:

```
 <div ng-repeat="m in messages">
        {{m.message}}
 </div>
```

[My issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44500791/7405844)